# Entity Class v Entity Bean

Tags: netbeans-7, ejb-3.1

What is the difference between an Entity Class and an Entity Bean? When I right click on Enterprise Beans in Netbeans 7.4 there is no Entity Bean option as shown below:

[image]

I am a .NET Developer.  I have spent time Googling but have not found an answer.

Comment: What do you want to do with this ? I think it is the same thing.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque, I am trying to create an entity bean that use container managed persistence.

Comment: That's entity class.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque, is there a good Container Managed Persistence example anywhere for Netbeans 7.4? All the tutorials I find seem to be very dated.

Comment: https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque, thanks for the link.  However, there does not seem to be a single reference to Container Managed Persistence.  I believe your link is showing how to use an ORM i.e. Java Persistence?

Comment: If you use an application server (container ?) maybe this one https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html#specification but it is the same. You don't deal directly with the Container, just some configuration after it's actually an ORM.

Comment: @ Mr_Thorynque, thanks.  Is Container Managed Persistence an alias name for ORM?

Comment: What is for you Container Managed Persistence ?

Comment: @ Mr_Thorynque, sorry I do not understand your question.

Comment: Yes it's an ORM but the standard in java ee. But now the key word is JPA.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque, this link states that CMP was replaced with JPA:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API

Answer (score 2):

To answer the title question:

1. Entity Bean refer to the EJB Spec 2.x
2. Entity Class is part of Java Persistence API (JPA) and is a "replacement" for Entity Bean, which are no more part of EJB 3.x, although backward compatibility is guaranteed

Then, related to it:

3. JPA is the ORM standard since JEE 5, and is basically a standard by Oracle, various vendor provide its concrete implementation (EclipseLink, Hibernate, ecc...). JPA is a specification itself
4. EJB 2.x the only transaction demarcation allowed is CMT = Container Managed Transaction, which means the app server (container) will manage the rollback if error occurs
5. CMP is not a replacement for JPA

If you are starting from scratch, maybe for learning purpose, always start with classic stack EJB 3.x (stateless, statefull, message driven, singleton) for business logic and Entity Class for persistence part.